# custom loop ad in wordpress

Tags: php, loops, search, ads

I am trying to show google ads in my website. I would like insert one at the top of the loop. 1st one and now more. It echo ad front every post, but I would like just show it once before the first one.

This is the code what I am using.

```
<div class="search-results">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $counter_max = 4;
        $column_size = 'col-sm-6 col-md-3';
        if( $ads_search_layout == 'style-left' ){
            $counter_max = 3;
            $column_size = 'col-sm-6 col-md-4';
        }
        if( $view == 'list' ){
            $counter_max = 2;
            $column_size = 'col-md-6';
            if( $ads_search_layout == 'style-left' ){
                $counter_max = 1;
                $column_size = 'col-md-12';
            }
        }

        $counter = 0;
        if( $ads->have_posts() ) {
            while( $ads->have_posts() ){
                $ads->the_post();
                if( $counter == $counter_max ){
                    $counter = 0;
                    echo '</div><div class="row">';
                }

                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_size ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    if(($counter>1) && ($counter == 0)){
                  echo( classifieds_load_path( 'includes/adsence.php' ) );
                    }

                    if( $view == 'grid' ){
                        $image_size = 'classifieds-ad-box-bug';
                        include( classifieds_load_path( 'includes/ad-box.php' ) );
                    }
                    else{
                        $excerpt_max = 154;
                        include( classifieds_load_path( 'includes/ad-box-alt.php' ) );
                    }
                      $counter++;
                    ?>

                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem? What are you trying to achieve? What is your code currently doing?

Comment: I am trying to put a google adsence ad front of the while loop, but so far I could do print and ad front of all posts, but I only want to put on the front of the first one. Thanks Sorry I am new on this site or using php.